# Menu Bar- clock-Big Sur

Tags: macos, menu-bar, clock

I am successfully using 'defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog -bool true' to replace to a smaller icon the Apple clock in Big Sur.

Is there a code to revert to Apple's clock if ever required?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a key will set it back to its default value.

```
defaults delete com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog
```

However, you don't even need to delve into defaults to make this change, to or from analog — it's in the UI: System Preferences → Dock & Menu Bar → Clock → Time Options.

[image]